# How to store XML file on client's system and access it through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xml

The problem is- I have a manage reservation page where I have table images of my restaurant. when I drag drop a particular reservation on a table, that table gets assigned to that reservation. When I click on tables image I show the table info in a popup. Now here comes the problem, to fetch table info page goes back to server(postback) and LINQ the collection and populate the info.This reduces the performance.`What I want to do is to serialize tableInfo collection and save that XML in client's system and rather than postbacking the page I can fetch the table details from that XML through javascript.` Is this possible?can I store that XML in clients machine?

**OR what else I can do to increase performance??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

One way would be to use [Web Storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) (either `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`), but that requires a browser that supports it (very few do).

**If** you only need the data in the context of a single page (or don't have a problem with requesting it once per page), then you can simply keep it in some global variable (for example as a property of the `window` object).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options with this.  First, you could continue to make the server side call but utilize jQuery/AJAX/loading images to make the wait less painful.

The other option would be to use HTML 5 local storage.  Stephen Walther has a good [example project](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2011/01/12/asp-net-and-html5-local-storage.aspx) of how to use it.